# How do you convert a keyCode received in an NSEvent to a character in the English alphabet when using a Japanese keyboard?

Tags: swift, macos, keyboard, appkit

After using a shortcut on a keyboard, I receive an `NSEvent` by overriding `NSApplication.sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent)`. I can get the Japanese character that was pressed from `event.characters` or `event.charactersIgnoringModifiers`.

However, the Japanese keyboard switches to English when you hold `CMD` and I would like to receive that English character instead of Japanese.

I checked `characters`, `charactersIgnoringModifiers`, `characters(byApplyingModifiers: .command)` and all return Japanese characters.

Is there any way to get the corresponding English character?

I know I could assume US QWERTY keyboard and just use hardcoded key codes, but I'm looking for a universal solution that works also with other keyboards. And I'm not sure if it is always US QWERTY after holding `CMD`. Also, I would need to be able to determine if this is a non-English alphabet keyboard.

Japanese keyboard:
[image]

Japanese keyboard when `CMD` is pressed:
[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create macOS application:

```swift
@NSApplicationMain
@objc class MyApplication: NSApplication {
    override func sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent) {
        super.sendEvent(event)

        print(even.characters) // Japanese
        print(event.charactersIgnoringModifiers) // Japanese
        // How to get an English character here?
    }
}
```

2. Change your keyboard to Japanese (Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources). To make it easier show the keyboard viewer like above.
3. Press for example `CMD+A` and check the output.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: In `NSApplication` override `func sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent)`, in Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources set Japanese keyboard. Press some combination `CMD+...` and check `event.characters`. You will get always Japanese character, but I need to know what is the underlying English character.

Comment: If you vote for closing have at least courage to write what's wrong in your opinion. Maybe I could fix that...

Comment: Close vote "Needs debugging details" = "How can we reproduce the issue?".

Comment: I added steps to reproduce in the description

Comment: Weird, most of the time `characters` is Latin and `charactersIgnoringModifiers` is Japanese. My virtual keyboard switches to Latin when I press the Option key. Maybe you can do something with `UCKeyTranslate`.

Comment: For now, I implemented a workaround where I check if a character for the hardcoded "A" keycode (0x00) is a Latin character. If it is I'm using `event.characters`. Otherwise, I assume it is the non-Latin keyboard and that keycodes are aligned with the US QWERTY keyboard. As far as I was able to check all non-English keyboards use US QWERTY after holding CMD.